# Tests failing with lombok and apt gradle plugin

Tags: build.gradle, lombok, mapstruct, gradle-apt-plugin

I have a project with mapstructs and lombok based on the mapstruct-examples/mapstruct-lombok/ but with latests versions and tests part is not working.

Even adding lombok dependency in testCompile the lombok annotations used in tests are failing when executing gradle test task.

The problem starts when I add the apt plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.13'  
}
```

and the apt at depencencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    apt "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}", "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    ...
}
```

At this point the lombok annotations stop working and fails in compilaJavaTest gradle task.

Not adding apt plugin makes lombok work properly but then I can't use mapstructs

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using `testApt` and the corresponding depencencies.